# calling a function on the first time won't work as expected, but next time is working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

here's my code:

```
treksID=[];
recommendedTrekId=2;

$(document).ready(function(){
    showTrek('random');
    showTrek(recommendedTrekId);
});

function showTrek(filter){
    if (filter=="random"){
        param={action:'getShortTrek'};
        tagId="#random";
        index=1;
    }
    else {
        param={action:'getShortTrek', Trek_Id:filter};
        tagId="#recommend";
        index=0;
    }
    $.getJSON('php/treks.php',
        param,
        function(data){
            $(tagId).find('h3').html(data[0].Trek_Name);//PROBLEM
            treksID[index]=data[0].Trek_Id;//PROBLEM
            if (filter=='random') {alert('debug'); test=data;}//DEBUG
        }
    );
}
```

On the first time `showTrek` is called it does everything as expected but not the two problematic lines (marked with //PROBLEM tags) the second time does work.
also after that when I call `showTrek('random');` in the browser console it does work.
what is strange is that data does contain the right object (checked by viewing test).

I'm feeling a bit crazy when programming does that, can anyone see my problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's because you declared your variables `param`, `tagId` and `index` as global by forgetting the `var` keyword. This makes their first values erased by the second call to `showTrek` and this call happens *before* the first callback you pass to `$.getJSON` is executed because the AJAX call is asynchronous.

You should simply add

```
var param, tagId, index;
```

at the start of the `showTrek` function.